# JSP page is not able to get the Bootstrap files from the resources folder -IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, intellij-idea, jstl

My project is running and showing the resulted page without inheriting any bootstrap properties 
Ive figured that the error is that my `home.jsp` is not able to get the correct path for the resources folder where all the bootstrap files are located

My HomeController is consist of just one method which returns the home page

This is my home.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: Wasi Khan
  Date: 01-11-2018
  Time: 01:40 PM
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Carousel Template for Bootstrap 3.3.6 Documentation - BootstrapDocs</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/carousel.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<!-- NAVBAR
================================================== -->
<body>
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <div class="container">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

    </div>
</div>


<!-- Carousel
================================================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img class="first-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="First slide">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Example headline.</h1>
                    <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img class="second-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Second slide">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img class="third-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Third slide">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->


<!-- Marketing messaging and featurettes
================================================== -->
<!-- Wrap the rest of the page in another container to center all the content. -->

<div class="container marketing">

    <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->

    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <footer>
        <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
        <p>&copy; 2015 Company, Inc. &middot; <a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
    </footer>

</div><!-- /.container -->


<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" />"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js" />"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am getting red text for path inside value parameter

```
 <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/carousel.css" />" rel="stylesheet">

<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" />"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js" />"></script>
```

*These are the lines from the above home.jsp files*

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

       <context:component-scan base-package="com.ecommercestore"/>


    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

[This is the picture of my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr3hx.png)

[This is the output i am getting after running the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N44J.png)

i guess i have made some mistake in the dispatcher-servlet.xml in the mvc:resources tag 
Please help?

Comment: Please check this tutorial for some tips: https://crunchify.com/spring-mvc-4-2-2-best-way-to-integrate-js-and-css-file-in-jsp-file-using-mvcresources-mapping/

Comment: I dont know why it's not working, i kept the resources folder inside webapp at the same level of WEB-INF no errors in the code still it is not able to access the bootsrap files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOUND THE ERROR !!!! 
In my HomeController class, in RequestMapping annotation i forgot to mention the ("/") so in the end it should look like RequestMapping("/") and it automatically found all the files despite of url value being in red text.